# Hyperledger Fabric : Error: could not assemble transaction, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 127

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am currently working on Hyperledger fabric. Trying to run the **fabcar** app from the **fabric-samples** but getting following errors.

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: containers exited with 127
```

Hyperledger Fabric source : https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples

I have already delete the older docker images and also container, and then started executing the script but still getting the error.

**CMD**

```
sudo docker rmi $(docker images -a)
sudo docker kill $(docker ps -aq)
sudo ./startFabric.sh javascript
```

please help me out, give me any suggestion to get the script working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chaincode is not properly classified. Firstly: to run this chaincode ./startFabric.sh u should be in the fabric-samples/fabcar directory. Secondly, check ur javascript, whether it is working or not. Anyway try these lines:

```
$sudo docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
$sudo docker ps -qa|xargs docker rm
$cd fabric-samples/fabcar
$sudo ./startFabric.sh (or ./startFabric.sh)
```